# Can I close an application when a negative button on a dialog is clicked?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have an app which uses Wifi to transfer some data. I have a dialog box appearing if the Wifi is disabled. The dialog box has two buttons: 'Yes' and 'No'. If the user clicks 'Yes', the wifi is enabled. If the user clicks 'No' the app should close itself. How can I actually make the app close on the click of the 'No' button?

Note: I use  a different class (other than the MainActivity) to perform the checks on the wifi status.

Comment: "How to close an android application?" has got to be a duplicate of ∞ questions.

Comment: @JeremyMiller I have checked many of those but I could not use some of those methods because I cannot call the startActivity() from a class which does not extend Activity, and some of them involved using killProcess() and I did not want to use that. I don't know if I've missed something as I am new to Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you cant access your activity from this class that you have created. The best way to deal with this problem is to use Listener interface. 
It allows you to capture the event when user clicks 'No' in dialog in you Activity class.

Create a interface in you class where you detect the dialog No click:

```
public interface DialogWiFiListener {
    public void callback(int response);
}

DialogWiFiListener mDialogWiFiListener;

public void setDialogWiFiListener (DialogWiFiListener mDialogWiFiListener) {
    this.mDialogWiFiListener = mDialogWiFiListener;
}
```

When you declare this class you use, you have to instantiate DialogWiFiListener object and call method setDialogWiFiListener , giving it your activity. Also inside your Activity you have to implement yourClass.DialogWiFiListener so it listens to the events.

To Finalize your work you have to call the listener object you have created when user clicks No in dialog

```
mDialogWiFiListener.callback(-1);// give -1 to detect his click
```

Then in  your activity you have this:

```
    @Override
    public void callback(int response) { 
       if (response < 0) {
           // here you manage your work when user clicked No in dialog
           Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
           startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
           startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           startActivity(startMain);
           finish();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really "smart" but it should work:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Answer (score 0):

You just call the `finish()` method of the activity/dialog you're trying to close. Killing the app can cause app lifecycle management issues.

Example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /*
    * You must call the finish() method on an instance of 
    * the activity/dialog you want to close
    */
    public void closeActivity() this.finish();

}
```

The actual call to the `finish()` method closes the application as it should, passing through all the [Activity's Lifecyle corresponding methods](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html).

Comment: How do I call the closeActivity() thus declared from a non-static method of a different class which does not extend Activity?

Comment: As you can see, I've defined a method named `closeActivity()` which may be called when the response of the dialog is either `positive` or `negative`. It depends on your implementation, and since you haven't provided any code, we can't help you more.

Comment: I have a class WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver which extends BroadcastReceiver class and a constructor call to it is made from the MainActivity. There is a method inside WifiBroadcastReceiver to check if the wifi is turned on or not. So from this method how can i call closeActivity()? Or is there some other way around this?

Comment: You must call that method on an instance of the activity you want to close, as the example suggests, you can call that method from inside of it as well. You may want to give feedback from your dialog to its parent to know wether or not should the method be called. [More info about the close method here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()), and [more info about dialogs here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Comment: I cannot instantiate the MainActivity can I?

Comment: You must instantiate it in order to show your app, otherwise you shouldn't be seeing your dialog. I suggest you read through [this pages](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) first.

Answer (score 0):

another way is just pass the intent of system home screen with clear top flag.
It will not force close your application but application will be closed for user.

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startMain);
```